# new instance vs standard function memory usage with socket.io events

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, socket.io

I work with typescript and socket.io. The standard solution looks like this:

```
socket.on('event', (msg: any, cb:Function) => self.eventFn(msg, cb));
```

The function of the event too long and deep because of many asynchronous call stack (300 - 600 line, 8 - 10 depth). To solve this annoying code design I start thinking about use classes instead of functions  like this:

```
socket.on('event', (msg: any, cb:Function) => new EventClass(msg, cb));
```

With this case I can separate the part of the process into small units and code re-usability is better too I guess. This looks good for me but, I fear this is use more memory, because I create a new instance on every socket event, and maybe it use more CPU too.

So, the question is: Is my fear a legitimate one?

Comment: About memory leak , try to check or track memory usage .

Comment: What do you mean by "The function of the event too long and deep because of many asynchronous call stack"?
Can't just call some external function?

Comment: The structure what we use is controller based, so for example there is user controller and all event listeners are in that controller, this means many event, and if we separate the parts into external functions we may have hundreds of functions. BTW maybe we should change the base concept and use one listener per file, so instead of controller base structure we should use event base structure. I dont know this is an acceptable way, but the question good, thanks! :)